# How to enable text wrap in this case?

Tags: flutter

I have a problem, if text doesn't contain \n line breaker, text is overflowing.
How to fix this? I've tried to wrap this text by widget Flexible or Explanded, but i got only error: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.

softWrap: true for text widget either didn't change anything.

[image]

This is full code of widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.w),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(() => UserInfoPage(), arguments: {
                    "userId": userId,
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: !additional
                      ? CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: avatar,
                          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 23.w, backgroundImage: imageProvider),
                          placeholder: (context, url) => CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 23.w,
                            backgroundImage:
                                AssetImage('assets/pics/loading.gif'),
                          ),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                              Icon(Icons.error),
                        )
                      : SizedBox(width: 46.w),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15.w,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: !additional
                        ? Text(
                            name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.w,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )
                        : null,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: !additional
                        ? SizedBox(
                            height: 5.h,
                          )
                        : null,
                  ),
                  type == 'text'
                      ? Text(message,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14.w,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200))
                      : Container(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _launchURL(message);
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text('PDF Anhang',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 14.w,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200)),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.download,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  size: 15.w,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16.h,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.w),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Text(messageTime,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3c3d58), fontSize: 11.w)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.h,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

and this is child widget of:

```
ListView.builder(
                          controller: scrollController,
                          reverse: true,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: _controller.messageList.length,
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w, right: 5.w),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Message(
                                userId: _controller.messageList[index].authorId,
                                type: _controller.messageList[index].type,
                                name: _controller.messageList[index].name,
                                avatar: _controller.messageList[index].avatar,
                                message: _controller.messageList[index].message,
                                messageTime: _controller.formatDate(
                                    _controller.messageList[index].messageTime),
                                additional:
                                    (_controller.checkAdditional(index)));
                          })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with text overflowing is likely due to the fact that your text doesn't contain any line breaks, and the `Text` widget tries to display it all on a single line. To fix this issue and allow the text to wrap when it reaches the edge of its container, you can use the `softWrap` property along with a `maxLines` property on your `Text` widget.

Here's how you can modify your `Text` widget to make it wrap properly:

```dart
type == 'text'
    ? Text(
        message,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 14.w,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
        ),
        softWrap: true, // Allow text to wrap
        maxLines: null, // Set maxLines to null to allow unlimited lines
      )
    : Container(
        // ... Your ElevatedButton code here ...
      ),
```

By setting `softWrap` to `true` and `maxLines` to `null`, the `Text` widget will automatically wrap the text when it reaches the edge of its container, and it will continue wrapping for as many lines as needed.

Make this modification in your code where you're displaying the message text, and it should prevent text overflow issues.

Comment: Hello, thank you for suggestion, but it doesn't help. just nothing happened after modification

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. If the previous suggestions didn't resolve the issue, let's try a different approach. Please let me know if it's not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've already tried using `softWrap: true` and `maxLines: null` in your `Text` widget to enable text wrapping, but you're still facing issues with text overflow. The "Cannot hit test a render box with no size" error typically occurs when the layout constraints are not properly set. To resolve this issue and ensure that text wraps correctly, you can try the following:

1. **Wrap your `Text` widgets in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget**: Wrapping your `Text` widgets in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget can help ensure that they expand to take up the available space and wrap the text properly.

   ```dart
   type == 'text'
       ? Flexible( // Wrap the Text widget in Flexible
           child: Text(
             message,
             style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 14.w,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
             ),
             softWrap: true,
             maxLines: null,
           ),
         )
       : Container(
           // Your ElevatedButton code here
         ),
   ```
2. **Ensure that the parent container has constraints**: The error you mentioned, "Cannot hit test a render box with no size," suggests that there might be an issue with the parent container not having size constraints. Make sure that the parent container of your `Text` widgets has proper width constraints so that the `Text` widgets know how much space they have to work with.

   ```dart
   Container(
     width: /* Set a specific width here */,
     child: type == 'text'
         ? Text(
             message,
             style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 14.w,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
             ),
             softWrap: true,
             maxLines: null,
           )
         : Container(
             // Your ElevatedButton code here
           ),
   )
   ```
3. **Check for other constraints in the parent widgets**: Ensure that none of the parent widgets, including the `Row` or `ListView.builder`, have constraints that prevent the child `Text` widgets from expanding as needed.